# User authorisation on mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb

I've created a database user, using the following command on the mongo shell:

```
use admin
db.addUser({user: 'test', pwd: 'test', roles : ["readWriteAnyDatabase"]});
```

This seems to work and when I do

```
show users
```

using the root admin user I created I can see the test user with the correct roles assigned.

However when i do

```
use admin
db.auth('test','test');
```

i get an error in the console saying

```
Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 }
```

Why is this? I can see the user is there but I can't authenticate.

Comment: what's the version of your mongodb?

Comment: I'm on version 2.6.5

Comment: hmm, nothing seems to be wrong. I copy&paste your code and it all works fine for me...

Comment: hmm, well thanks for looking. Problem must be with the install or something. Although, it installed without any issues and I've already tried a re-install

Comment: Ok, here the sysadmin part of me jumps in: Have you started mongodb with `--auth` enabled?

Comment: If not, first create a root or useradmin.

Comment: Yeah I have a useradmin - created with a ['userAdminAnyDatabase'] role

Answer (score 0):

The addUser function expects a document. See: [addUser documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/). You're missing the curly braces in your parameter.

```
db.addUser({user: 'test', pwd: 'test', roles : ["readWriteAnyDatabase"]});
```

Comment: no sorry, that's just a typo. I've definitely added the user, using a document. I've checked the user is there with "show users"